# Writing a custom function for groupby column

Tags: python, pandas, function, group-by, pandas-groupby

Trying to write the following custom groupby function to count the percentages of 1s in a given binary column, b:

```
def _get_perc(ds):
    try: 
        return ds.value_counts(normalize=True).loc[1]
    except KeyError: 
        return 0.0
df[['group','b']].groupby('group').apply(_get_perc)
```

But pandas is taking ds as a dataframe instead of a Series; it gives me an 
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'.

How should I write the function to take ds as a Series?

Comment: can you give example df = ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just index the `GroupBy` object with a series label:

```
def _get_perc(ds):
    try: 
        return ds.value_counts(normalize=True).loc[1]
    except KeyError: 
        return 0.0

df[['group','b']].groupby('group')['b'].apply(_get_perc)
```

Answer (score 3):

Specify that the grouping is to be done explicitly on column `b`.

```
df
   group  b
0      1  0
1      1  1
2      2  0
3      2  0
4      2  1

df.groupby('group')['b'].apply(_get_perc)
group
1    0.500000
2    0.333333
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

The pre-indexing step is not needed.

---

Alternatively, `value_counts` can also be called directly on `Series`:

```
df.groupby('group')['b'].value_counts(normalize=True).xs(1, level=1, axis=0)

group
1    0.500000
2    0.333333
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

The additional `xs` step is to select the normalised counts of 1s.